# How to use MultiByteToWideChar in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, utf-8, character-encoding, utf-16

I need to convert "ÖÐÎÄ°æ²âÊÔ" into Chinese characters "中文版测试".
I see this function for c++ MultiByteToWideChar:

```
MultiByteToWideChar(
    CP_UTF8,            // convert from UTF-8
    0,                  // default flags
    utf8.data(),        // source UTF-8 string
    utf8.length(),      // length (in chars) of source UTF-8 string
    &utf16[0],          // destination buffer
    utf16.length()      // size of destination buffer, in wchar_t's
    )
```

But how can I use that into vb.net?

Comment: [**`Encoding.Convert()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdcak6ye(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @VisualVincent: Or [`Encoding.GetString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc.aspx), which is more commonly used.

Comment: `ÖÐÎÄ°æ²âÊÔ` is bytes `D6 D0 CE C4 B0 E6 B2 E2 CA D4` in Latin1. That is NOT a valid UTF-8 byte sequence, so you can't decode it as UTF-8 to UTF-16. `中文版测试` is bytes `2D 4E 87 65 48 72 4B 6D D5 8B` in UTF-16, and bytes `E4 B8 AD E6 96 87 E7 89 88 E6 B5 8B E8 AF 95` in UTF-8 (`ä¸­æ–‡ç‰ˆæµ‹è¯•` in Latin1). I don't see how you would get from `ÖÐÎÄ°æ²âÊÔ` to `中文版测试` in any direct conversion. What are you really trying to accomplish? `ÖÐÎÄ°æ²âÊÔ` looks like possible [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). Where does it come from exactly and why do you think it represents `中文版测试` at all?

Comment: `String` is not for binary data. If you encode a string with an encoding, it becomes binary data. "ÖÐÎÄ°æ²âÊÔ" seems to be some sort of reinterpretation of such binary data back to `String` using an entirely different encoding, simply to store it in a `String` (intentional, reversible mojibake). It would be much clearer to keep binary data in a byte array along with the knowledge of which character encoding is used to convert it to text. In any case you need to identify the unknown encoding.

Answer (score 0):

From the reverse engineering (guessing) department, there are combinations of encodings accessible in .NET on my machine that can decode this *sample*.

```
Dim mojibake = "ÖÐÎÄ°æ²âÊÔ"
Dim text = "中文版测试"
Dim possibilities = 
    From mojibakeEncoding In Encoding.GetEncodings()
    Let orginalBytes = mojibakeEncoding.GetEncoding().GetBytes(mojibake)
    From originalEncoding In Encoding.GetEncodings()
    Where originalEncoding.GetEncoding().GetString(orginalBytes) = text
    Select New With { 
        .mojibakeEncoding = $"{mojibakeEncoding.Name}", 
        .originalEncoding = $"{originalEncoding.Name}" }
possibilities.Dump()
```

([LINQPad](http://share.linqpad.net/auh2c4.linq) code)

Keep in mind that a different sample might give different results so it's best to figure out how the mojibake was created to begin with. Ideally, you would eliminate the use of character encodings to store binary data. You could use Base64 instead.